# How validate hyperlinks in a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink

Is there any easy way to scan through a notebook in order to validate hyperlinks there that point to targets (tagged cells) within the same notebook?

By this I mean at least that the hyperlink's target cell tag is actually there.

(The issue arises as I rewrite and edit a complex notebook with various sections, subsections, display equations, etc., to which I have hyperlinks.

That is, some way without reading through the entire notebook and trying each hyperlink there?

I have in mind some tool (eventually, I would hope, in the form of a palette) that would do the same sort of hyperlink validation that some HTML editors provide.

Comment: This is too vague. You should at least give an algorithm for deciding what constitutes a valid link.

Comment: Are the following steps enough:
1. Mark a word in the notebook
2. Go to Menu/Insert/Hyperlink. The dialog "Create hyperlink" pops up.
3. Under "Destination notebook" check "Current notebook".
4. In the right-bottom window all tag show up. One can check, if the tag in question is still there. 

I guess that there should also be a nicer programmatic way to do the same.

Comment: That 4-step procedure is the very tedious manual method I'm trying to shortcut somehow!